# How to do clustering on a set of paraboloids and on a set of planes?

Tags: geometry, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry, hierarchical-clustering

I am performing cluster analysis in two parts: in the first part (a), it is clustering on a set of paraboloides and in the second part (b), on a set of planes. The parts are separated, but in both I initially had one set of images, on every image of which I have detected the points to which I (a) fit the paraboloid and (b) the plane. I obtained the equations of the surfaces (paraboloids and planes) so now I have 2 sets of data, for (a) it is the array of the arrays of size 6 (6 coefficients of the equation of the paraboloid) and for (b) it is the array of the arrays of size 3 (3 coefficients of the equation of the plane).

I want to cluster both groups based on the similarities of (a) paraboloids and (b) planes. I am not sure which features of the surfaces (paraboloids and planes) are suitable for clustering.

For (b) I have tried using the angle between the fitted plane and the plane *z = 0* -- so only 1 feature for every object in the sample.
I have also tried simply considering these 3 (or 6) coefficients to be seperate variables, but I believe that this way I am not using the fact that this coefficients are connected with each other.

I would be really greatful to hear if there is a better approach what features to use except merely a set of coefficients. Also, I am performing hierarchical and agglomerative clustering.